# Binance API entering order gives me MIN_NOTIONAL

Tags: c#, api, async-await, cryptocurrency, binance-api-client

I'm currently using an open source Binance API from nuget, called
Binance.Net from JKrof
https://github.com/JKorf/Binance.Net

I already have my API and keys in place, but when i tried to enter either Market or Limit order, using this....

```
// Market Order
var dd = await client.SpotApi.Trading.PlaceOrderAsync(order.symbol, side, SpotOrderType.Market, order.orderqty, null, order.clordid);

// Limit Order
var dd = await client.SpotApi.Trading.PlaceOrderAsync(order.symbol, side, SpotOrderType.Limit, order.orderqty, null, order.clordid, order.price, TimeInForce.GoodTillCanceled);
```

the Response is i get FAIL, and this is what it reads.....

```
   "ResponseTime":"00:00:00.0633524",
   "OriginalData":"{\"code\":-1013,\"msg\":\"Filter failure: MIN_NOTIONAL\"}",
   "Error":{
      "Code":-1013,
      "Message":"Filter failure: MIN_NOTIONAL"
   },
   "Success":false
```

I have no idea what this means, it seems the parameter i used is correct, What can i do to not use filter or anything. I dont understand even a market order i get this error.

Can anyone help?

Comment: https://use.autoview.with.pink/hc/en-us/articles/360003301752-Error-1013-Filter-Failure-MIN-NOTIONAL-or-Invalid-Quantity

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ok, my qty is too low. i just needed to increase the qty. thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).